# Rust variable types types for generic structs

Tags: generics, rust, variadic-templates

I have a struct that I want to be able to accept a variable amount of Types. In C++, the language I used most, there are [type packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which have a syntax like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts> // Capture types
struct Foo {
    std::tuple<Ts...> Bar; // Unpack types
};
```

As far as I have seen on my research there isn't something similar like this in rust, but there is a [`type`-type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html), so I thought there might be a way to use an array of types for this:

```rust
struct Foo<Ts: [type]> {
}
```

This, however, does not compile. I have also tried this:

```rust
struct Foo {
   Bar: [type]
}

let foo = Foo { Bar: [i32, usize] };
```

But the rust compiler gives the error that the `type`-type is not actually not a type at all.

Comment: Rust does not support variadic type parameters in any form. What is your use case? Perhaps you can use a declarative macro instead.

Comment: @PitaJ A hash map with any number of types where each type can be used as both key and value.

Comment: Please give an example of the hash map you speak of.

Comment: @PitaJ A working implementation of it in C++ can be seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280618/multiway-map-in-c).

Comment: Rust does not support variadic types like that, and also doesn't support function overloads. The language is really just not well suited to that kind of abstraction. It's possible to get close with flagrant use of traits and declarative macros, but you would only be able to implement up to, say, 32 types.

Comment: @PitaJ Would it be possible to at least implement a biMap/triMap with similar semantics to the C++ implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Rust does not have variadic generics. The alternative to use will depend on the details of your application; here are two possibilities:

1. Use tuples. That is, you have a `struct Foo<T: MyArgs> {}` where `MyArgs` is a trait that is implemented for tuples `()`, `(T,)`, `(T,U)`, `(T,U,V)` and so on up to the maximum number of types you want to support.

   (This is how Rust's function traits handle argument lists. Unfortunately, you can't currently take any benefit from that.)
2. Use “heterogenous lists” such as are provided by [`hlist`](https://docs.rs/hlist/) or [`frunk`](https://docs.rs/frunk/0.4.0/frunk/). Here you build type-level linked lists — sort of like `Foo<(T, (U, (V, ())))>` except with dedicated types instead of tuples, and some helper macros for making it more readable. This allows you to support arbitrary numbers of types, provided you can express your problem in terms of type-level recursion/induction (by defining your own trait which is implemented for the list types).